# Storing a lot of values in Cassandra collections

Tags: cassandra, datastax

DataStax [recommends](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html) to store very small amount of records in Cassandra collections.

> Keep collections small to prevent delays during querying because Cassandra reads a collection in its entirety. The collection is not paged internally.

Are there any other consequences except for high latency during querying (heap pressure)?

Assuming that the records are immutable, will it be more effective in terms of querying/writing to store thousands of distinct records in Cassandra table comparing to a single frozen list storing the same records?

Answer (score 0):

*Are there any other consequences except for high latency during querying (heap pressure)?*

Collections are retrieved in its entirety. As long as you don't have to filter out within the list and retrieve the entire chunk to be used by application, then its just more heap memory and row cache memory usage along with added latency.

*Assuming that the records are immutable, will it be more effective in terms of querying/writing to store thousands of distinct records in Cassandra table comparing to a single frozen list storing the same records?*

The key word is immutable. Without "FROZEN", any insertion or non incremental updates to a collection data type results in a tombstone. The FROZEN keyword avoids that tombstone generation. So its always recommended to create FROZEN collection essentially immutable ones or replaced in entirety.

For additional [reference](http://www.sestevez.com/on-cassandra-collections-updates-and-tombstones/)

Comment: Any questions/comments on the response provided above? Otherwise please remember to accept/upvote the answer